# Not computable but left computable number

Tags: computability

I can't find an example of number that is not computable but it is left computable.
In general is already difficult to give example of non computable numbers, but I can't even find any number which is not left computable.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S:
A real number $x$, is said to be left computable number if the set $\{q\in\mathbb{Q}\vert q<x\}$ is recursively enumerable (that is, it is the image of a Turing machine).

Comment: What is the definition of left computable number?

Comment: All computable numbers are left-computable. It's the converse that is not true.

Comment: @MarkSaving I added it to the post. Basically, it means there is a Turing machine that enumerates all rationals below the number. Obviously this machine never halts, but for any rational it gets to it in finite time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there computable reals that are not Dedekind-computable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4098667/are-there-computable-reals-that-are-not-dedekind-computable)

Comment: @user3257842 Ah yes, right. Do you have any examples of that? Maybe consider some set $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ that is r.e but non recursive?

Comment: @miraunpajaro In fact, if a number $x$ is computable, then the set $\{q \in \mathbb{Q} \mid q < x\}$ is decidable by a Turing machine, not merely enumerable, as you can see in the cited post.

Comment: I will write one as an answer.

Comment: @MarkSaving Yes, I got it the other way around, sorry. The link solves my original question, but does not provide an answer to the "correct" question. Anyway, it helps me a lot, so thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/487237/365433) definition of left-computability, our aim is to construct a computable increasing sequence of rationals that converges to a non-computable number.

Consider a sequence $q_{n}$ subunitary rational numbers.

Define the $k$'th digit after the decimal point of $q_{n}$ to be $1$ if $k \leq n$ and the program encoded by $k$ halts after $n$ steps or less, or $0$ otherwise.

The $q_{n}$ are increasing, as a digit that becomes $1$ stays $1$ for all $q_{p}$ with $p>n$. They are also rational, as each $q_{n}$ has at most $n$ non-zero decimal places. However, their limit will be a number $q$ who's $k$th digit is $1$ if the program encoded by $k$ halts, or $0$ otherwise. As it encodes the solution to the halting problem, it is not computable.

Thus $q$ is left-computable, but not computable.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. I do not understand why computable implies left computable. Computable means there is "fast" computable convergent sequence, while left computable requires any computable sequence as long as it is increasing.

Comment: You can take a computable number $q$ and easily compute for it an increasing sequence, ie $q_{n}$, made of the first $n$ digits of $q$ for example.